# Proc Rank Alternative Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sas

I have a variable which contains score ranges from 1 to 321. When I use the below code in SAS.

```
proc rank data = test1 out = sorted groups =1000;
var score; ranks rank; run;
```

I get the output shown below:

```
  score | rank
   1    | 3
   2    | 6
....
320     | 993
321     | 996
```

I am trying to replicate the same in python by using the below code:

```
mylist= list(range(1,322))
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'score': mylist})
x = pd.qcut(test1.score, 1000, labels=False)
```

but I am getting the below output

```
0        0
1        3
...
319    996
320    999
```

As you can see above, In python binning starts from zero. Is there a way I can replicate the results of
SAS in python by making minor adjustments to my mentioned python code or any other methods are preferred too.

Comment: Could you share a test data sample in order for us to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function = lambda x: pd.Series(pd.qcut(x,1000,labels=False),index=x.index)
test1['ranks'] = test1.apply(function)
```

**EDIT**
The solution above is indeed not quite what you were looking for. It's because the `qcut` solution is not a copy of the SAS `proc rank`, so I went back to see what `proc rank` actually does. It does a grouping as well anf the formula for doing so is:

The formula for calculating group values is as follows:

```
FLOOR(rank*k/(n+1))
```

where

1. rank is the data value's rank order
2. k is the value of the GROUPS= option
3. n is the number of nonmissing values

So, I modified the approach:

```
mylist= list(range(1,322))
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'score': mylist})
test1['rank'] = test1['score'].rank()
test1['grouping'] = round(test1['rank']*(1000-1)/(len(test1['score'])+1))
```

Ranking first, grouping second (`Floor` in pandas is `round`). This gives
Note! The `len(test1['score'])` is to be taken over non-null elements. Note also, the `k-1`. It also is the case in SAS.

```
     score   rank  grouping
0        1    1.0       3.0
1        2    2.0       6.0
2        3    3.0       9.0
3        4    4.0      12.0
4        5    5.0      16.0
..     ...    ...       ...
316    317  317.0     983.0
317    318  318.0     987.0
318    319  319.0     990.0
319    320  320.0     993.0
320    321  321.0     996.0

[321 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: btw, OP answer is better `test1['ranks'] = pd.qcut(x,1000,labels=False)`, problem is not assign, but binning

Comment: Fixed it! Added a description of what ```proc rank``` actually does.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I am looking for. The description is spot on and totally makes sense. Thanks heaps @Serge